# City Data Attribute

Tags: c++

So I have basically been trying to add population attribute to a city. I think I basically have it but I keep getting the error "Requires a type specifier for all declarations".

```
// citytest.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class City
{
  char name[12];
  char population [6];

  public:
    City( char input[] )
    {
      strcpy( name, input );
    }

    char* getName()
    {
      return name;
    }

    PopN( char input[] ) <--- This bit is cause the error
    {
      strcpy( population, input );
    }

    char* getPop()
    {
      return population;
    }
};

int main( void )
{
  City acity( "Cambridge" );
  cout << "City is: " << acity.getName() << endl;
  City pop( "300000" );
  cout << "City Population: " << pop.getPop() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Hopefully all this is enough to suggest why it is doing this.

Comment: Like all of your other functions, `PopN`, must have a return type.  If you do not want to return anything then you use `void` as the return type.

Comment: Population should surely be an integer. And learn about std::string.

Comment: The error message isn't totally explicit, but from "requires a type specifier", one might infer that a type is missing somewhere...

Comment: Ahh okay thank you guys and will do Neil, I am kinda just starting out in C++ so trying to get my head around it, I was thinking integer.

Comment: @Henry If you are just starting out, it's all the more important that you learn C++ using things like std::string, rather than C language features like character pointers.

Comment: Okay I shall go and learn those instead thanks for the help!